# Should I use count(*) on a very common query or store the number

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have two tables (a lot more actually, but only interested in these two).

```
USER_ACTION (ID, ID_USER, ID_ACTION, TMST) AS A
ACTION (ID, DATA, NUM_USERS) AS B
```

However, B.NUM_USERS is actually a representation of the number of records in USER_ACTION that have A.ID_ACTION = B.ID

Is this acceptable as performance optimization (a very common query recovers ACTION data very often), or since this breaks the relational model it is a bad idea and the query should be:

```
SELECT B.ID, B.DATA, count(*) AS NUM_USERS 
FROM ACTION B JOIN USER_ACTION A ON A.ID_ACTION = B.ID
WHERE B.ID = ?
GROUP BY B.ID
```

If this second option is the correct answer, is there any index I should put in place to optimize this query?

-- EDIT --

After running Explain with current model, but anonimyzed (8 users for the selected action):

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys       key         key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      B       const   PRIMARY             PRIMARY         8       const   1   
1   SIMPLE      A       ref     FK_USER_ACTION  FK_USER_ACTION      8       const   8   Using index
```

Comment: what are the datatypes of `A.ID_ACTION` and `B.ID` ?

Comment: All IDs are `BIGINT`, `B.DATA` is actually a lot of fields

Comment: run the following on mysql and share the result on the question, `explain SELECT B.ID, B.DATA, count(*) AS NUM_USERS 
FROM ACTION B JOIN USER_ACTION A ON A.ID_ACTION = B.ID
WHERE B.ID = ?
GROUP BY B.ID ` , hardcode some value for B.ID

Comment: Have a look at the query cache (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html). If you don't have too many different ID_ACTION, then this might work for you without leaving the strict database model.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty added the EXPLAIN fo the query... seems good, no?

Comment: How many total rows the table has ?

Comment: currently Action a few millions and USER_ACTION about 10% more but increasing rapidly... repetitions are scarce and highest reaches 10k.

Comment: ok then the indexes are working and the query is good, you can check if the tables are indexed properly by using `show indexes from table_name` and make sure that `A.ID_ACTION` and `B.ID` are indexed since you are using them in join as well as in where and then all should be good with this query :)

Comment: So the optimization of storing the number seems a bad idea to you... correct?

Comment: no its not, as long as your table is indexed and your query is using them properly it should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend keeping the query as you described it and adding an index on ID_ACTION in USER_ACTION and ID in ACTION.

Your where filter and group by will both benefit from the index on ACTION, and the join to USER_ACTION should be an eq_ref join (for more info http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/), which will be fast in most cases. Use EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of your query to verify the action plan. If you start to notice any slowness, you could also index DATA in ACTION using a compound index on (ID, DATA). That would give you a covering index, but I doubt if the cost of indexing DATA with ID is really worth it (for more info: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/... old, but still applicable)

In general, if many  count(*)'s were several thousands of rows, you might want to consider a summary table via a materialized view or a cron job or whatever. It's still slower to count(*) over (say) 100k rows than it is to precompute that. But basically you shouldn't notice much slowness until you're dealing with several thousands rows in USER_ACTION that need to be count(*)'d in order to return the result. I don't think you're going to have that problem, frankly... so you should be fine using the join you described with the indices I did. Use EXPLAIN EXTENDED to verify that. Also note that LRU will probably come into play a bit here, if you're using INNODB (eg http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html). Just something to be aware of, a concept you'll want to realize exists.

Comment: thanks, on production the highest count is around 10k users, so it seems acceptable. It just bothered me to have non relational data on a relational database, but i wasn't sure if it was a reasonable optimization from my predecessor or a mistake I could correct.

Comment: I would add the indices mentioned and look at the Query Execution Plan with EXPLAIN. I'd also check for duplicate ID_ACTION or IDs, just to be safe. If you're on a really weak box, 10k might be a problem... but in most production SQL boxes I've seen, that should be fine. I'd expect the slow part of this query to actually be the table read of b.DATA, which precomputing the COUNT(*) won't help with anyway.

Comment: I added the plan on the edit for an example row... your opinion good sir? this query might sometimes be called by users very often.

Comment: It looks good, yes. run SELECT id, count(*) FROM USER_ACTION GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5; Pick those five ids and run explain  with them. But basically this looks good. It may be called by users very often.... cool. LRU will give you a hand with that.